# Can you quickly tell me if this pseudocode makes sense or not?

Tags: java, recursion, pseudocode

[image]

I believe my code is now foolproof. I will write up the pseudocode now. But I do have one question. Why does DRJava ask that I return something outside of my if statements? As you can see I wrote for ex: "return 1;" just because it asked. It will never return that value however. Can someone explain this to me?

```
public class assignment1question2test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[50];
    int l = 0;
    int r = a.length;

    for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
      a[i] = 1;
    }

    a[0] = 10;

    for (int i=0; i<r; i++) { 
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    System.out.print(recursiveSearch(a,l,r));

  }

  public static int recursiveSearch (int[] a, int l, int r) {

    int third1 = (r-l)/3 + l;
    int third2 = third1*2 - l + 1;

      System.out.println("i will be checking compare from " + l + " to " + third1 + " and " + (third1 + 1) + " to " + third2);
      int compareResult = compare(a,l,third1,third1 + 1, third2);

      if(r-l == 1) {
      if (compareResult == 1) {
        return l;
      }
      else {
        return r;
      }
      }

      if (compareResult == 0) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,third2 + 1, r);
      }
      if (compareResult == 1) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,l,third1);
      }
      if (compareResult == -1) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,third1 + 1, third2);
      }
      return 1;

  }
  public static int compare(int[] a, int i, int j, int k, int l) {

    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    for(int g=i; g<=j; g++) {
      count1 = count1 + a[g];
    }

    for(int g=k; g<=l; g++) {
      count2 = count2 + a[g];
    }

        if (count1 == count2) {
          return 0;
        }
        if (count1 > count2) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (count1 < count2) {
          return -1;
        }  

        return 0;
}
}
```

UPDATED FINAL PSEUDOCODE:

```
Algorithm: recursiveSearch (a,l,r)
Inputs: An array a, indices l and r which delimit the part of interest.
Output: The index that has the lead coin.
int third1 ← (r - l + 1)/3
int third2 ← third1*2 - l + 1
if (r-l = 0) then
    return l
int compareResult  ← compare(a,l,third1,third1 + 1,third2)
if (r-l  = 1) then
    if (compareResult = 1) then
        return l
    else 
        return r
if (compareResult = 0) then
    return recursiveSearch(a, third2 + 1, r)
if (compareResult = "1") then
    return recursiveSearch(a,l,third1)
if (compareResult = "-1") then
    return recursiveSearch(a,third1 + 1,third2)
```

Comment: Outside of the fact that you're missing a few variables from your mathematical definition, `compareResult = "="` won't work for two reasons - the first being that you're using the assignment operator as opposed to the comparison operator (and the other being you can't do that with a String).

Comment: The density of [lead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead) is `11.34` and [gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold) is `19.3`, almost *double* that of lead, so the fake coin would be significantly *lighter*, not heavier. Tell the person who set the problem (s)he is a moron, unworthy of judging your intellectual effort.

Comment: Can you check it again? I added info

Comment: @Bohemian Not to mention the fact that in the real world this "weighing multiple coins at once" saves time because "the universe's physics engine" does the adding for you but on a computer its insanely stupid

Comment: @Makoto It looks like his assignment operator is `←`, leaving `=` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including `mid` in the following search regardless of which side is larger.  The recursive calls should both exclude `mid` from their search space.

Also, for the comparison to be meaningful, the two groups being compared need to be of equal size.  That will require some extra odd/even logic.

Comment: For the comparison to be meaningful, the two groups being compared need to be of equal size. That will require some extra odd/even logic.

Comment: i know, but i tried instead to divide the problem into thirds. comparing third1 with third2 will tell me if its in third1 or third2, but if theyre equal then i know its in the last third

Comment: `count2 = count1 + a[g];` should be `count2 = count2 + a[g];`

Comment: For some reason it is not working for certain values of the index.

Comment: I just wanted to answer a question about pseudocode... why am I debugging Java?

Comment: no ones forcing you to do anything. you dont need to, though i appreciate your help.

Comment: it works now... though i have one question. why does drjava ask that i put a return outside of an if statement? because my program doesnt depend on it, am i supposed to just write 'return any_value;'?

Comment: final pseudocode has been written. i believe this is the right answer.

Comment: I bet drjava won't complain if you change that to an "if...else if...else".  It just isn't understanding your code thoroughly enough to know that one of those returns is guaranteed to be reached.

Comment: the only returns i have are inside if statements, because i know that every time one of the if statements will be true. is drjava just trying to protect me in case none of the if statements render true? in such case, what could i do?

Comment: Yes, and you can use `else` to indicate that the last condition must run if the previous ones didn't.  That will save you a compare operation, too.  (I would also change the second if to an "else if".)

Comment: two ifs and an if 'else if' are the same thing, no?

Comment: Not precisely - if the first "if" condition is true, an "else if" following it will be ignored (not even tested), while a regular "if" following it will be tested normally.  I consider it good style to use "else if"s for conditions that can't both be true.

Comment: i dont think you can have an "else if" for the second, and then an "else" for the last as well, because the "else" will close after the 2nd "if", and then there will be no "if" to create an "else" from

Comment: The "if" to create the final "else" from is the "if" in "else if"