# Does my pseudocode make sense?

Tags: java, pseudocode

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/tOfrn.png]

I believe my code is now foolproof. I will write up the pseudocode now. But I do have one question. Why does DRJava ask that I return something outside of my if statements? As you can see I wrote for ex: "return 1;" just because it asked. It will never return that value however. Can someone explain this to me?

```
public class assignment1question2test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[1];
    int l = 0;
    int r = a.length-1;

    for(int i=0; i<=r; i++) {
      a[i] = 1;
    }
    a[0] = 10;

    for (int i=0; i<=r; i++) { 
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    System.out.print(recursiveSearch(a,l,r));

  }

  public static int recursiveSearch (int[] a, int l, int r) {

    int third1 = (r-l)/3 + l;
    int third2 = third1*2 - l + 1;

      if (r-l == 0) {
        return l;
      }

      System.out.println("i will be checking compare from " + l + " to " + third1 + " and " + (third1 + 1) + " to " + third2);
      int compareResult = compare(a,l,third1,third1 + 1, third2);

      if(r-l == 1) {
      if (compareResult == 1) {
        return l;
      }
      else {
        return r;
      }
      }

      if (compareResult == 0) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,third2 + 1, r);
      }
      if (compareResult == 1) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,l,third1);
      }
      if (compareResult == -1) {
        return recursiveSearch(a,third1 + 1, third2);
      }
      return 1;

  }
  public static int compare(int[] a, int i, int j, int k, int l) {

    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    for(int g=i; g<=j; g++) {
      count1 = count1 + a[g];
    }

    for(int g=k; g<=l; g++) {
      count2 = count2 + a[g];
    }

        if (count1 == count2) {
          return 0;
        }
        if (count1 > count2) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (count1 < count2) {
          return -1;
        }  

        return 0;
}
}
```

FINAL PSEUDOCODE I THINK

```
Algorithm: recursiveSearch (a,l,r)
Inputs: An array a, indices l and r which delimit the part of interest.
Output: The index that has the lead coin.
int third1 ← (r - l)/3
int third2 ← third1*2 - l + 1
if (r-l = 0) then
    return l
int compareResult  ← compare(a,l,third1,third1 + 1,third2)
if (r-l  = 1) then
    if (compareResult = 1) then
        return l
    else 
        return r
if (compareResult = 0) then
    return recursiveSearch(a, third2 + 1, r)
if (compareResult = "1") then
    return recursiveSearch(a,l,third1)
if (compareResult = "-1") then
    return recursiveSearch(a,third1 + 1,third2)
```

Comment: Write it in code, test it, see what happens... Also, is this any different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420029/can-you-quickly-tell-me-if-this-pseudocode-makes-sense-or-not)?

Comment: "A king owns n gold coins, stored in an array". There’s something hilarious about that

Comment: Why did you tag this with Java? Anyway, I suggest you compare by thirds. If you think about it, there's a clever optimization that way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Which also nicely deals with the problem of "What do you do if you have a non even number of coins" since the 3rd stack of coins can be a different size to the first two (although similar sizes gives best efficiency)

Comment: why did you post your question twice?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why compare by thirds?

Comment: @piyukr Each "compare" as writen gives half1 has coin or half2 has coin. Splitting by thirds gives third1 has coin, third2 has coin or third3 has coin but still with only 1 operation (if third 1 and 2 are equal it must be in third 3)

Comment: @piyukr Because it's more efficient. You can eliminate 2/3 of your possible chandidates with every comparison (instead of half).

Comment: its no different but i couldnt get any answers on it

Comment: @user3245760 When that happens edit your question to make it clearer rather than reposting

Comment: Agreed.So if I compare by quarters I do even better?

Comment: @piyukr Thats impossible, the function gives 3 outputs, "equal", "side1 heavier", "side2 heavier". You need to efficiently use all 3 possible outputs. Thirds uses all 3, whereas halves basically ignores the "equals" output

Comment: @piyukr Probably not. This problem usually only gives you one "balance". You could make it constant time if you had "n/2" scales.

Comment: its not so easy to write in code because the compare method isnt real

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @piyukr I have `n` coins. One of the coins weighs more or less then the others. If I have `n/2` balances, I can put one coin on each side of each balance (using `n` coins), only one should be out of balance; and that's the one that weighs more (or less).

Comment: @piyukr Imagine this, I have 60 gold coins. I put 30 on one scale, 30 on the other. One side is heavier. I know the lead coin is in that stack of 30. **OR** I put 20 on one side, 20 on the other. Either one is heavier and the coin is in there, or **they are the same** and the third stack of 20 contains the coin. Either way i've now only got 20 coins to search

Comment: @user3245760 check the code for binary seacrh. It will give you an idea of how to deal with such problems.

Comment: whats an easy way to divide my array properly into thirds?

Comment: @piyukr That is the even case, for the odd case; it's the same... only I have one coin I'm still holding. If all the balances are equal, the coin in my hand is "funny".

Comment: @user3245760 given that this is just a puzzle you can just add up all the enties in the two regions and compare them. It won't be efficient, but it doesn't need to be. (I for one say this is a puzzle that has nothing to do with programming as this isn't a more efficient way to do this because the 1 array based compare operation is very expensive compared to a simple direct coin compare)

Comment: Got it now.Yeah,spliting in thirds minimises the calls to compare().

Comment: im unsure whether i should be comparing from say 'a to b' with 'b to c', or 'a to b' with 'b+1 to c'. should i be trying to make use of the fact that compare returning an '=' would let me know where the lead coin is?

Comment: and i dont really understand why odd/even matter for comparing in thirds

Comment: @user3245760 Remember in the real world you can't have a coin on both sides of the scals (and its silly anyway) so its b+1. Regarding using the "=" you need to read what we've been saying aboutr splitting in thirds

Comment: ok, you are right about that. it will let me know that its not in the first two thirds.

Comment: @RichardTingle I updated my post... idk what to doo. i believe this works better but im not 100% sure about how size of the array will affect it

Answer (score 0):

You should refine you logic more, it doesn't consider the case where the number of coin is even.

Odd: take a coin out, divide the remaining into 2 equal half and do the comparison.

Even: divide the remaining into 2 equal half and do the comparison.

For recursive function, please also define the base case:

When n=1, return the coin.

When n=2, return the heavier coin.

```
NumberOfCoin = r-l+1
if (NumberOfCoin = 1)
    return l;
if (NumberOfCoin = 2)
    compare(a,l,l,r,r)
        0:      Think it yourself
        -1:     Think it yourself
        1:      Think it yourself
if (NumberOfCoin is odd number)
    mid = Think it yourself
    compare(a, l, mid-1, mid+1, r)
        0:      Think it yourself
        -1:     Think it yourself
        1:      Think it yourself
if (NumberOfCoin is even number)
    mid = l+r/2
    compare(a, l, mid, mid+1, r)
        0:      Think it yourself
        -1:     Think it yourself
        1:      Think it yourself
```

Comment: what do you think of it now?

Comment: Think it yourself, it is your assignment. you have to put equal number of each side to make a comparison meaningful.

Comment: well i almost have the code completely written for the method of dividing it into thirds, except sometimes it doesnt work. i will paste this up now

Comment: Ok, dividing into 3 groups is more efficient than 2 groups. but you should follow the more or less format. Please define the base case for NumberOfCoin= 1 and 2.

Comment: I have finished the code. Gonna write up the pseudocode now.

Comment: i have one question about the code.
< int third1 = (r-l)/3 + l; >
should this be
< int third1 = (r-l+1)/3 + l; >
So basically should I be adding 1 to the amount I divise by 3? I'm a little confused. I think both work either way, but still

Comment: How about you write it on the paper start from 3->13 and count it to check if you are putting same amount of coin on both side of the balance.

Comment: updated with pseudocode. i know im putting the same amount on both side, because the int 'third2' depends on the difference between the first indice and third1. so they will be the same. but im unsure which is technically more accurate to splitting in thirds. i think it is +1, because then you are including the 0th position?

Comment: nevermind. it should be third1 = (r-l)/3 +l,  NOT (r-l+1)/3 +l. This is because it wont work for size of 3 otherwise.

Comment: You'll need the +1 for the case when there are only 2 elements left to compare.

Answer (score 0):

String compareResult  ← compare(a,l,mid,mid,r)

Here you check the middle element twice, make it:

String compareResult  ← compare(a,l,mid,mid+1,r)
Apart from that your algorithm seems fair enough to me.